# Fabric.js image/text disappears when drawing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I have set up `Fabric.js` in my react app using the fabric npm package. I am trying to build an art board where you can draw, add text and add images. For some reason adding elements (images/text) seems to break the app. When adding an image the image appears for some time then disappears when some change occurs and re-appears when selecting any other image/text.

The point is while drawing, only drawings are visible and when adding elements, only elements are visible while all of them (objects) are present on the canvas.

I have created a similar environment to simulate the issue, please let me know of any fixes.

NOTE: The main code is in the `fabricCanvas.js` file which creates a class to handle all of `fabric.js` features.

[CODESANBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/amazing-violet-fvmhcg) (Updated)

I added a check as well to check if the image is present on Canvas by mapping all objects, and it's there but for some reason not visible.

I also tried a solution of removing the `strict` mode but it doesn't help.

I have tried different solutions of calling `renderAll()` on every update, but that doesn't work as well.

Comment: There is nothing inside your sandbox link. Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

There is many problem with your initialization

using fabricJS with useEffect

first :

```
        <div 
            id="canvas-container" 
            ref={containerRef} //use ref on the container to observe his size
            style={{ maxWidth: "100vw", overflow: "hidden" }}
        >
            <canvas id={canvasID} />
        </div>
```

Then define your ref

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);
const canvasID = "canvas";
```

Now you can use use Effect  hook to run initialization logic when the component mounts

```
/**
* Effect hook to run initialization logic when the component mounts or 
when the container changes.
*/

useEffect(() => {

const container = containerRef.current;


/**
 * Checking if the container exists before proceeding with initialization.
 */

if (!container) {
  console.error("❌ The container does not exist");
  return;
}

/**
 * Getting the initial dimensions of the container.
 */
const clientHeight = container.clientHeight;
const clientWidth = container.clientWidth;

/**
 * Create the main canvas
 */
fabricCanvas.init(canvasID, clientWidth, clientHeight);


}, []);
```

At this step the canvas is working.
But in react you want to dispose the canvas in case of your component is dismounted.
What i suggest is to separate your canvas initialization and your different features. store your canvas into a context or a state manager of your choice

look a this example :

```
 useEffect(() => {

    const container = containerRef.current;

    /**
     * Checking if the container exists before proceeding with initialization.
     */
    if (!container) {

        console.error("❌ The container does not exist");
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Setting the container reference in the fabricStore for future use.
     */
    fabricStore.setContainerRef(container);

    /**
     * Getting the initial dimensions of the container.
     */
    const clientHeight = container.clientHeight;
    const clientWidth = container.clientWidth;

    /**
     * Create the main canvas
     */

        initCanvas(clientHeight, clientWidth);

  
  // your different config to initialize
        initControls();
        initWorkspace();
        initBackground();
        
    /**
     * once the canvas has been created
     * your different features
     */

    if (fabricStore.canvas) {
            new FabricFeature02(fabricStore.canvas);
            new FabricFeature03(fabricStore.canvas);
            new FabricFeature04(fabricStore.canvas);
            new FabricFeature05(fabricStore.canvas);
    }



    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
        const { width = clientWidth, height = clientHeight } =
            (entries[0] && entries[0]?.contentRect) || {};
        resizeCanvas(width!, height!); // your resize logic 
    });

    // Attaching the ResizeObserver to the container, assuming the container is of type HTMLDivElement.
    resizeObserver.observe(container as HTMLDivElement);

    /**
     * Returning a cleanup function to be executed when the component is unmounted.
     */

    return () => {

        //Disposing of the canvas using the dispose method, assuming it exists in the fabricStore.
        fabricStore.canvas?.dispose();

        // Checking if the container element exists before attempting to disconnect the ResizeObserver
        if (container) {

            // Disconnecting the ResizeObserver to stop observing changes in the container size.
            resizeObserver.disconnect();

        }
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: It worked, disposing of canvas solved my problem, just added another method to dispose the canvas when the component unmounts.
Thanks a lot, you are a life savor!

Comment: Il hope it help you il explain as much as possible . usestate hook update your components eatch time it receive a new value then your canvas is fully re render.